# Alternative to start thread inside of an mvc .net core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, iis, asp.net-web-api

There is currently multiple instruments inside of our manufacture plant that are inserting data into multiples tables inside of a database at different speeds.

There is a computer on each production line connected to a web page where the operator enter the assigned job number and some related information is displayed.

Our goal is to display indications base on the data inserted by the plant devices. Status are related to raw material availability, warehouse storage availability, temperature range, etc.

My initial idea was to modify the current MVC application by spawning a thread per production line that is scanning the inserted information each 10 seconds and may push data trough signarlR to advice operators. I read that starting threads inside of an MVC application is a bad practice that may disturb how IIS manage threads.

I was wondering how to host fast-recurrent-independent processes in MVC if it is not by using a separate thread?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, starting polling threads might not be the best approach here. An alternative solution that I might suggest is to modify your so called *instruments* (that are currently inserting data) to be SignalR clients and broadcast a message to the server each time they insert some data. The SignalR server could then simply broadcast this message to the javascript SignalR clients connected to it. This way you could achieve direct communication (through the SignalR server) between the instruments that are producing data and the browser clients that can display this data in real time.

Comment: I am sorry, I will add more information. The devices are using PLC programmed in ladder, something that is industrial and realtime. It does exclusively support CRUD operation on the database.

Comment: Additionally, I would like to keep the business rules calculation on the server because we are using more and more to integrate data to others systems like the ERP.

Comment: Then you probably want to abstract the CRUD operations behind some API that your devices will call so that you could easily notify the SignalR server about the incoming updates. Believe me you totally don't want to be spawning polling threads in an ASP.NET application. That's like wanting to shoot yourself in the foot.